# How do I use std::getline to match expected input and read a variable portion?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, getline

How do I use `std::getline` to read input with a constant part and variable part..
for example:

**`constant part`**: "`I_love`"

**`variable part`**: "`cat, dog, donkey, bird.....`"

And I tried this code by writing: `I_love cat`

But i realized that `"cat"` will not be in string `Variable`, it will be with the **`constant part`** and **`variable part`** will not have any value
I want to have `cat` in the string `Variable`

Please can any one tell me what is the problem??

```
std::string UserInput, Variable;
std::getline(std::cin,UserInput);
if (UserInput == "constant_part" + Variable)
{
    .....
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping expected characters like scanf() with cin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764826/skipping-expected-characters-like-scanf-with-cin)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a `std::string` to a `const char *`. You can, however use `operator+` to concatenate two strings, so:

```
if (UserInput == ( std::string("constant_part") + Variable) )
```

Answer (score 0):

`getline` can be used to read everything (including whitespace) up to either End-Of-File or the next instance of the delimiter character, which you may specify as an argument or leave as the default '\n'.  So, you can use it like this:

```
if (std::getline(std::cin, UserInput, ' ') && UserInput == "I_love" &&
    std::getline(std::cin, Variable))
    std::cout << "the animals loved are: " << Variable << '\n';
```

If you want to extract the individual animal names one by one:

```
if (std::getline(std::cin, UserInput, ' ') && UserInput == "I_love")
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    while (std::cin >> skipws && std::getline(std::cin, animal, ','))
        std::cout << "someone loves their " << animal << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your obvious problem of using brackets correctly to group expressions, a solution like this:

```
if (UserInput == ("constant_part" + Variable))
```

will create a new temporary of `std::string` and compare.. You can improve this by finding the length of the **`constant part`** and then do a `substr`.

```
std::string UserInput, Variable;
std::getline(std::cin, UserInput);

//example...
auto LengthOfConstantPart = sizeof("constant part ")/sizeof(char);

//Then you simply do
Variable = UserInput.substr(LengthOfConstantPart);
```