# Proper usage of operator >> subsequent times on same input stream

Tags: c++, c++11, input, stringstream

I'm writing some code in order to read some parameters values from a file.

I know that if, let's say, I have a `stringstream` object `stream` created from the string `"10"` I can initialize a numeric variable defined as `int var1;` just by typing:

```
stream >> var1;
```

What if now my `stringstream` object is created from the string `"10;3;4.5;3.2;"` and I have four variables declared as follows:

```
int var1;
int var2;
double var3;
double var4;
```

Can I write something like this:

```
stream >> var1;
stream >> var2;
stream >> var3;
stream >> var4;
```

in order to initialize all the four variables from this stream? Or my only option is to implement a simple parser to extract each value one at a time and then store that value into each one of them?

Well, in fact I tried it and it doesn't work. `var1` gets initialized correctly but the other variables are all initialized to 0.

Can you explain why this doesn't work? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the streams well enough to give an explanation, but maybe the answer to this question (declare ; as a whitespace character) helps as an alternative to writing your own parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764826/skipping-expected-characters-like-scanf-with-cin

Comment: Doesn't explain why this fails but shows you how you can do it.  Just replace `,` with `;` since you have semi-colon serarated data and not comma separated data.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with streams is a bit tricky but also interesting at the same time.
To parse this using stringstreams, just modify the code a little to take into account the semicolon. Here is how:

```
//  stream = "10;3;4.5;3.2;"
stream >> var1;
//  stream = ";3;4.5;3.2;"
//  now if you will input stream >> var2,
//  will extract till the next integer value exists.
//  But here, since character ';' and not an integer, it won't pass any value to var2.
//  To correct it, add this line to take are of the ';' :
char ch;
stream >> ch;
stream >> var2 >> ch;
stream >> var3 >> ch;
stream >> var4;
```

To understand this, you need to get a better understanding of how the stream extracts input from the input buffer. I've tried to explain it step by step.

For a better understanding on this topic refer to this: 
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/184-stream-classes-for-strings/